# how to show value of textbox type=date asp.net

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, textbox

I have a textbox with the property `type="date"`. I am able to retrieve the value in backcode but when I try to assign a value, the placeholder `"mm/dd/yyyy"` is shown.

When I view the markup, the expected value is there - `"value='01/01/1991'"`. I think it has to do with JavaScript overriding the value.

Any suggestion on how I can work around this?

Edit: Sorry, forgot to include the markup and code

So my markup is

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthdate" runat="server" class="form-control input-sm" type="date" onkeypress="handleEnter(event)" />
```

and c# is

```
txtBirthdate.Text = usr.BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

the resulting markup is

```
<input name="ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$Body$Body$Body$Body$txtBirthdate" value="01/20/1991" id="ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Body_Body_Body_Body_txtBirthdate" class="form-control input-sm" type="date" onkeypress="handleEnter(event)">
```

So as you can see, the value was assigned.

Comment: show some .aspx and .cs what u tried

Comment: please share some html code or JSFiddle will be better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this only happens in Chrome. It requires value assignment to be in "yyyy-MM-dd" format. Try in your C#

```
txtBirthdate.Text = usr.BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This should display the correct value (and it doesn't affect the format of the display).

If will display in this format in other browsers tho. You may want to do some browser detection, e.g.

```
if (Request.Browser.Browser == "Chrome")
{
    txtBirthdate.Text = usr.BirthDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
} else {
    txtBirthdate.Text = usr.BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

but perhaps something more sophisticated

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
txtBirthdate.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(TablaHabitacion.Rows[fila].Cells[6].Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English-only site, please do not use languages other than English